# Access user control text box in parent views controller using mvc 3 razor engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to create user control in mvc3. i am in middle of this process and i am little confused too. how to create user controls in mvc3 using razor engine and how can i reuse the same user control in many views? also i have to access controls inside user control in parent views controller. how to do this?

**My scenario is, i will generate some dynamic string inside user control and assign to text box in user control. now i have to access value inside that text box from parent view's controller**.

Update:

I have button inside usercontrol(partial view) to generate dynamic string. so over all i have two button one is inside user control another is inside parent view. both are indepedent process. button inside partial view has to call some controller to generate dynamic string and assign to textbox inside partial view.but Button inside parent view controller has to get that value.

Comment: There is a perfect tutorial on codeproject:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224378/Custom-Controls-for-MVC3

Comment: sorry i was not able to understand that link content. because i am new to mvc 3 reazor.

Answer (score 0):

why not try to use the partial view and then accessing the elements created in the partial view from parent view.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/aravindbenator/mvc-3-razor-and-partial-view/

Comment: pls see my update. i have to get value back from partial view

Comment: 1) to create a controls you have options crate them from the model passed to the partial view or generate them using jquery and here is a good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384829/how-to-get-partialview-data-in-controller